# Flutter. Displaying result of calculation as either int or double. (num?)

Tags: flutter

Question regarding Flutter.

I wish to display the result of a sum as either a int or a double. (I believe this is a 'num' right?)

I am sorry if this seems vague or super simple or whatever. I am a code noob.

At the moment I have:

```
  TextEditingController weight = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController distance1 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController distance2 = new TextEditingController();
  String result ='0';
```

(Then I have some text input fields with the corresponding text controllers attached)
A button performs and displays the math:

```
onPressed: (){
                setState((){
                  num sum1 = num.parse(weight.text) * num.parse(distance1.text) ~/ num.parse(distance2.text);
                  result = sum1.toString();
                });
              },
```

I have some text which displays the result but this is always an int.

I have tried to convert 'result' to a num also using num.parse along with other various ideas but nothing seems to work. I have no idea what is suppose to be done.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, u can use double because of the result can have a fraction

```
onPressed: (){
            setState((){
              double sum1 = double.parse(weight.text) * double.parse(distance1.text) / double.parse(distance2.text);
              result = sum1.toString();
            });
          },
```

if you get only specific value of fraction use

> sum1.toStringAsFixed(3) // here 3 is your faction value what you want

Comment: Thank you for your reply, however I get an error when I use 'double sum1 ='

The code seems to allow 'int sum1 =' or 'num sum1 ='